# Dynamic path for data-template in angular-strap bs-popover directive

Tags: angularjs, popover, angular-strap

I have used the angular-strap 'bs-popover' directive to open a popover using a custom html template. Following is the code sample which calls the directive when an input field is clicked.

`<div ng-controller="ctrl">
<input size="6" type="text" ng-model="cell.HHmm__c" data-template= "/projectA/v/d/views/popoverTemplate.html" data-animation="am-flip-x"  bs-popover="popover"></input>
</div>`

Everything is working fine. However, now I want to set the data-template using a string variable in my controller. As an example, assume I have a variable

> $scope.templatePath = "/projectA/v/d/views/popoverTemplate.html"

in my controller **ctrl**. If so, how do I assign the variable **templatePath** as the data-template path in my bs-popover directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have two way to do this

```
ng-attr-data-template="{{templatePath}}"
```

OR

```
data-template="{{templatePath}}"
```

Hope this could help you, Thanks.